# How do I return IDs for which only a single record is returned in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have currently trimmed a section of my data set, but I need to filter it further.

My goal is to isolate only those IDs for which a single row is returned.

For example, with a data set as follows:

```
ID          Client Name                  Client Manager
1           XYZ Corp.                    Ralph
2           Bob's Marketplace            Marianne
2           Bob's Marketplace            David
3           Davis Auto Repair            Ralph
3           Davis Auto Repair            Marianne
4           Everything Inc.              David
5           Pet World                    Marianne
```

I need to return:

```
ID          Client Name                  Client Manager
1           XYZ Corp.                    Ralph
4           Everything Inc.              David
5           Pet World                    Marianne
```

Comment: HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, 
       Client_Name, 
       Client_Manager
FROM table_name
WHERE ID IN 
(
    SELECT ID 
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: Count(1) didn't work for me.  I had to use Count(*) to get this to work in MS Access.

Comment: Sorry, the question wasn't flagged MS Access.  Either way, I'm glad that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, [Client Name], min([Client Manager]) as [Client Manager]
FROM dbo.Table1
GROUP BY ID, [Client Name]
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: You solution would work fine and probably compiles similar to the selected answer.  I suggest that the downvote was because your solution would be expensive (because it would have to find the min).  I +1 since your answer would produce the correct result - however I would return the code to you if you wanted to put it in *my* production.

Comment: @DanAndrews , thank you for the cheers up, actually the -1 was because an error in the original script. Agreed that the damage could be very high.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ID, [Client Name], [Client Manager] FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN 
(
  SELECT ID FROM Table1
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1
)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote and our answers look similar and I have +1.  Eh... StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table a, (SELECT ID FROM your_table
                    GROUP BY ID
                    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID;
```

[see SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9334/1)

Comment: You solution would work fine and probably compiles similar to the selected answer.  I suggest that the downvote was because it's not easy to read.  I +1 since your answer would produce the correct result - however I would return the code to you if you wanted to put it in *my* production.